# Shrink a snapshot consists multiple ebs volumes on root into one

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have snapshot an EC2 instance contains 3 ebs volumes (RedHat pv / vg / lv, due to historical mis-judgement) on root (means "/", no chance to unmount) and bootable. I would like to shrink to a single ebs bootable volume. On the original or on a brand new ebs is fine.

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: An Amazon EBS Snapshot can only contain data from one Amazon EBS Volume. Have you considered simply launching a new instance from a desired AMI and re-loading your data/apps?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein actually it's EC2 instance snapshot. have fixed it. sorry for confusing.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "EC2 instance snapshot". Are you referring to an AMI?

Comment: Yes. That AMI required 3 ebs volumes to run. Remove one of three will make it non-bootable.

Comment: Whoa, that configuration sounds like it is in bad shape! If possible, I would definitely suggest starting again from a clean AMI image and reinstalling whatever you want on it.